# Does this exist: instrument that measures voltage at many points on a pcb?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm imagining an instrument that has many very sharp and fine needles. Sharp enough to pierce soldermask and fine enough not create any shorts. You then lower this device onto your board and it measures the voltage at each needle point and displays it on the computer with a cool graphic.

Comment: Yes. Its called a bed of nails test fixture. It usually makes contact from the foil side.

Comment: I haven't seen BoNs fixtures that poke through soldermask, I've always seen them contact test points specifically placed on the PCB, but that's just my experience.

Comment: Yes, it is a standard test procedure for PCB manufacturers, except poking through solder mask, where specially placed test pads are used instead. It is called "DFT", design for test.

Comment: Pogo-pins come in all tip shapes from rounded to sharps that will pierce coatings, or soft solder.  https://www.emulation.com/catalog/pogo/    ...these are standard for all sorts of test fixtures.

Comment: such intrusive testing is unheard of. Unless testing is done for few of the boards, whose test points are also covered with some kind of coating for protection

Comment: @DavidG25 Read THIS http://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/Nepcon99.pdf

Comment: ATE vacuum fixtures come bottom side and clam-shell top and bottom and also flying probe types. These are outsourced to Test houses and used by Contract Manufacturers with ATE worth 300k~1M$ each such as GenRad 228x, Agilent 307x, Teradyne Spectrum 88xx and Z18xx  . The ATE Test Engineer works with System and PCB Designer to ensure DFT and ATE meet production needs.  Costs start around $2k and go way up.  However what you suggest is naive.

Comment: @Tony. DFT sweeps rarely are 100% accurate or complete, so there are virtually always points on a board that need probed and are not nicely left uncovered and gold plated. It's seems completely naïve to describe ATE with hundreds of test points with neither placement or point errors in production. If your naïve perspective was true, then there would never be the need for such a range of tip types. Yet there they are.

Comment: yes and the epoxy screen piercing anvil probes x spring force x every test node = a massive lever forced ATE fixture We had over 10k ATE fixtures once, and a dozen ATE machine including old Functional CA Marathon's that could do Bode Plots. But I dont recall one having to meet these poor design specs, But we once demo'd a machine that could Reverse Engineer schematics from the test data. The % fault detection/isolation beds to be cost effective and functional "BITE" with external testers completes the 100% but only by good design.  99% of failures are solder

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Do you guys think I should delete this question? I am pretty new to stackexchange.

Comment: @DavidG25: no. Questions and answers are meant to be up for all time for the benefit of everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The device you are imagining is called a bed-of-nails test fixture. However, the soldermask is not typically pierced; instead, test points (pads with no component associated) are added to the PCB design as needed.

The “needles” are *pogo pins*, contacts designed for the purpose consisting of an appropriately-shaped tip (which may be sharp, merely conical, concave, etc. depending on whether it is touching a pad, hole, or already-installed component) backed by a spring to provide consistent pressure for each individual contact.

A related device specifically for bare PCB continuity testing, which is necessarily slower but does not have to be made to match the specific board design, is the *flying-probe* tester, which has two or more XY positionable contacts which are operated by computer control to sequentially test for continuity (or lack thereof, as appropriate) between many pairs of points on a board.

Comment: Do you know if PCB manufacturers perform exhaustive tests on the boards after manufacturing? Or they only check in critical places with high tolerances?

Comment: The classic "It Depends" is the answer. The key is how important is it? That is usually evaluated in terms of cost for a failed product in terms of money, time and reputation.